# Why does updating a stopped Azure deployment take so long?

Tags: windows, deployment, azure, cloud

Complete Azure deployment [takes a while for a reason](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5080445/57428), but here's what I do.

I stop the deployment, then while it is in "stopped" state I click "upgrade" and choose the service package. The deployment gets into "upgrading" state and it takes up to three minutes to complete and after that it gets into "stopped" state. I have to click "start" and wait for several more minutes to start the deployment.

I don't get it. The deployment doesn't need to be stopped prior to upgrading - it is already stopped. The deployment isn't started after upgrading. What is taking three minutes then?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you stopping the deployment?  The point of the upgrade is to get zero-downtime.  You should simply choose upgrade and either do a manual or automatic rolling upgrade across your upgrade domains.  Only new deployments require a stop/delete.

Comment: Here's the scenario: I upgrade my deployment, see that the role wouldn't start and would restart in a loop writing tons of error messages into the log. I read the log and identify the problem and I need time to fix my code and redeploy the role. I don't want the role to restart and continue writing messages into the log until I redeploy. So I want to stop the role ASAP once I know what to do.

Comment: You are missing the benefit of the upgrade then.  Use the manual upgrade method, check your logs, and if errors then simply stop the upgrade after 1 upgrade zone.  Next, reapply the original package to the partially upgraded deployment (upgrade zone 1) and you are back to your original state.  Now you can fix the upgrade and try again later.  Again, no need to stop.

Comment: That's too much manual labor. And also I don't ask how to get the most of Azure portal. I'm just very curious why it takes three minutes to do what seems to be trivial.

Comment: Not really sure what to say to that.  Redeploying an entire application across your servers in under 6 mins...?  I guess if you want something faster you need to invest in creating your own generic worker role that pulls its binaries from blobs (I have my own).  Smarx has one somewhere... smarxrole perhaps?  Those update in a min or so.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is because the automated upgrade is careful to make sure that you could start the Azure service again at any time during the upgrade - so it still takes its time upgrading the individual upgrade zones separately.